# Incrementing in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to increment a field in mysql but it seems that it is not really working for some reasons ...

That is the query I run in mysql query:

```
UPDATE profil_perso
SET profile_views = profile_views +1
WHERE id = 30537
```

In the status bar it says : 1 row affected by the last command. No resultset returned. But it didn't seemed to work. At first I thougth that it was simply because there were no rows at all. So then I ran this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM profil_perso
WHERE id = 30537
```

And found 1 row and the profile_views field is still at 0...

Any ideas of why this would be that way ?

[edit]
profile_views = 1 (set manually) at this moment and it still doesn't work.

Comment: you make select in the same transaction?

Comment: So what was the case? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you forget to commit a transaction when working with an `InnoDB` table?

**UPDATE:**

Since it's a `MyISAM`, I'll ask yet a couple of stupid questions:

1. Are you absolutely sure you're issuing `UPDATE` and `SELECT` against one database?

   I once had a large farm of databases with identical schemata, and this used to be a problem when someone deleted something from the wrong database.

   - Aren't you using some kind of client caching on your client? What client are you using?

And try to `REPAIR` your table, this also may be the issue.

Comment: Man ... how foul I am ... it's working totally ok now. I was selecting from the _dev db instead of the _production db. Lol! It's weird, the _production db was in bold both times. Totally working now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to verify - is profile_views zero, or null?  If you add 1 to null, you still get null, so that could be your problem.

ETA:

So it isn't null.  Next question would be, do you have autocommit on or, if not, did you issue a "commit"?  Could be that it was updated, but your update never committed.

Comment: It is at zero. 

I thought at first that it would be this and set it to 1. Still remains at 1 after the update.

Comment: The table is MyISAM so it's not supposed to affect it, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's null, won't increment.

```
UPDATE profil_perso
SET profile_views = IF(profile_views,profile_views+1,1)
WHERE id = 30537
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some parens and a coalesce to see if that fixes it:

```
UPDATE profil_perso
SET profile_views = ( COALESCE(profile_views,0) + 1 )
WHERE id = 30537
```